# Authorization depending on request parameter value with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I am wondering how to best handle authorization when authorization depends on a specific request parameter with spring boot.

In my specific scenario I do have an entity "Decision" that has an owner. The owner is the user who created the "Decision". REST APIs accessing this Decision should only be allowed by either the owner or a user that has the ADMIN role.

In summary I do have

- A REST API POST /decisions that creates a "Decision"

  - This API is allowed for all authenticated users. The user who creates the decision becomes the owner of it, i. e. the entity "Decision" has a property owner where the user id is stored.
- A REST API GET /decisions/{decisionId}

  - The owner and users with the ADMIN role should be able to call it
- I am able to get the user id of the user that makes the request
- I am able to get the roles of the user that makes the request
- I am able to get the information whether the user that makes the request is the owner of the decision or not.

Where would you do this authorization check? In the controller? In the service? Somewhere else? Implementing the check would probably easy. However, I would like to keep my controller and service as clean as possible. This is my main concern. I could add annotations like @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')") to the controller, but this actually would block the decision owners from accessing the API. What I need would be something like @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or isOwnerOf(decisionId)"). The isOwnerOf method would be something that I need to implement. Wondering if there is such a mechanism.

Do you have any hints how to best handle such situations with spring boot?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I was able to solve it with:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')  or @securityService.isDecisionOwner(#decisionId)")
```

securityService is a class with the @Service("securityService") annotation and a isDecisionOwner annotation. decisionId is the name of a method parameter.